# Do binary files have encoding? Confused

Tags: c, encoding, binaryfiles

Suppose I write the following C program and save it in a text file called Hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
 {
     printf("Hello there");
     return 0;
 }
```

The `Hello.c` file will probably get saved in a UTF8 encoded format.

Now, I compile this file to create a binary file called `Hello`

Now, this binary file should in some way store the text "`Hello there`". The question is what encoding is used to store this text?

Comment: The stored object file will have a format that is probably either proprietary to the compiler or a standardised format such as ELF. The string will be stored in there somewhere but where and how is defined by the compiler. The resulting executable after final linking will have its format dictated by the OS you are running on.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, vanilla C doesn't have any concept of encoding, although if you correctly keep track of multi-byte characters, you can probably use an encoding. By default, ASCII is used to map characters to single-byte characters.

You are correct about the string "Hello there" being stored in the executable itself. The string literal is put into global memory and replaced with a pointer in the call to printf, so you can see the string literal in the data segment of the binary.

If you have access to a hex editor, try compiling your program and opening the binary in the editor. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSDdI.png) is a screenshot from when I did this. You can see that each character of the string literal is represented by a single byte, followed by a 0 (NULL). This is ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

The translation between characters in the source code and characters in the resulting program is implementation defined. gcc gives command line options to control this behaviour. Other compilers probablly have similar options.

From  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

> -fexec-charset=charset
>
> Set the execution character set, used for string and character constants. The default is UTF-8. charset can be any encoding supported by the system’s iconv library routine.
>
> -fwide-exec-charset=charset
>
> Set the wide execution character set, used for wide string and character constants. The default is one of UTF-32BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-16BE, or UTF-16LE, whichever corresponds to the width of wchar_t and the big-endian or little-endian byte order being used for code generation. As with -fexec-charset, charset can be any encoding supported by the system’s iconv library routine; however, you will have problems with encodings that do not fit exactly in wchar_t.
>
> -finput-charset=charset
>
> Set the input character set, used for translation from the character set of the input file to the source character set used by GCC. If the locale does not specify, or GCC cannot get this information from the locale, the default is UTF-8. This can be overridden by either the locale or this command-line option. Currently the command-line option takes precedence if there’s a conflict. charset can be any encoding supported by the system’s iconv library routine.

You may also want to read https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html

In general, if the source character set doesn't match what your source code is written in, or the execution character set assumed by the compiler doesn't match what is expected by the APIs you pass your strings to then you may get errors or mojibake.

Mostly this is something you have to start worrying about when you want/need to use characters that go beyond those in ASCII.